# Tool to extract java class hierarchy and call graph from source code (using api)

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, static-analysis

I'm trying to find tools to extract structure from java source files, such as call graphs, class hierarchy, etc. The kind of thing a UML tool would use (but not the part which visualizes the graph).

I have previously used doxygen and may revert to it if there isn't a good solution. I'm looking to get at the raw graph and am not too concerned with html/pdf renderings.

Obviously netbeans, eclipse and countless other IDEs already do this analysis, but I'm having trouble finding the correct set of classes/utilities.

Same thing with tools such as findbugs/pmd/checkstyle, they do source code analysis, but the part which extracts relevant structure doesn't seem to be documented.

Note that I'm not looking to extract this information from jar files or compiled java classes, I'm looking to do this analysis at the source level.

Comment: For the Eclipse the core analysis code is the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html)

Comment: Maybe you can try [soot](http://sable.github.io/soot/) if you really need *precise* call graph.